# VUE filters through array

Tags: vue.js

I recently started out with vuejs and the idea is to make a POS system with it. So currently I have an array of products and display them etc that all works just fine. Now my problem is when trying to calculate the sub-total price (price without the added VAT) of all products together.

So here is what I currently have:

```
<div class="col-md-12 productsList">
            <div class="product" v-for="product in products">
                <p>
                    <span class="col-md-4">@{{ product.name }}</span>
                    <span class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">@{{ product.amount }}</span>
                    <span class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" v-text="(parseFloat(product.price) * product.amount) | float"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

<script>

new Vue({
    el: '.container-custom',

    data: {
        products: []
    },

    ready: function() {
        var self = this;
    },

    methods: {

        fetchSingleProduct: function(productId) {

            this.$http.get('get/products/'+productId).then((product) => {

                var existingProducts = this.products.filter(function (item) { return (item.id == product.data.id)});

                if (existingProducts.length) {
                    existingProducts[0].amount += 1;
                } else {
                    product.data.amount = 1;
                    this.products.push(product.data);
                }
            });

        },

    },

    filters: {
        float: function (value) {
            return value.toFixed(2);
        }
    }
});
```

Each product holds:
name, amount, price, vat

Each product's vat can be different too (some products have  6%, some 21%) etc. How would I accomplish such thing with vue?

Answer (score 0):

Just add all products that you need to sum into array and then create a computed property that returns the sum of that array with either  `array.reduce` or a simple `for loop` ...

Comment: on `reduce()`for suggesting `for`.